# >why is cookie not delivered to the react app from the node express server

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, cookies

when i hit the below express server from my react app which is running on port 3000 there is no cookie delivered however in postman there is?

```
const cookieParser = require("cookie-parser");
const express = require("express");
const cors = require("cors");
const app = express();

app.use(cors());
app.use(cookieParser());


app.get("/api", function (req, res, next) {
  const cookieOptions = {
    expires: new Date(Date.now() + 90 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000), 
    secure: false, 
    httpOnly: true, 
  };

  res.cookie("isCookie", "react cookie", cookieOptions);
  res.status(200).json({
    status: "success",
  });
});

app.listen(7000, () => {
  console.log("listening on port 7000");
});
```

the  client side react component making the request

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  async function getCookie() {
    let res = await fetch("http://localhost:7000/api");
    res = await res.json();
    console.log(res);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getCookie();
  }, []);

  return <div className="App">App</div>;
}

export default App;
```

Comment: Are you using proxy settings to redirect requests to the server? In that case you need to set the parameter credentials: true in your request to send cookies. It is described in detail here 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40896925/create-react-app-proxy-works-only-with-fetch-api-but-not-in-simple-get-of-the-br

Comment: While making request from the client side using URL as `/api` should help. Could you please try it out and check.

Comment: after setting proxy as "proxy": "http://localhost:7000" and  client request as /api, the cookie is delivered . Thanks